# How do I store the results of NDsolve, in a table for plotting later?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Basically, I wanted to vary a parameter in my differential equations, while using NDsolve (ParametricNDsolve wasn't working for some reason, but that's for another question). I'm stuck looking for the correct command for the last part in the following code section (Very sorry for the crappy formatting).

```
For[e = 0, e < 6, e++, {Sol = NDSolve[{H[t] == -e*g[t], g[0] == g[2*Pi],
```

`g[Pi] == 1}, g[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]};`

 `<Command to insert g[t]/.Sol in a Table>]`

My intention is to then plot all the solutions hence stored in the Table, using another loop, in a single graph. If this can be done directly, please provide some hints how.

Comment: use `Sol ={}; For[.e ==0, .., AppendTo[Sol,NDSolve[....]]`?

Comment: You should take a look at `ParametricNDSolve`. That will make your life much easier. Also: forget `For` exists in Mathematica. Use `Table` or `Do` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `Sol` is *replaced* by the new solution in every iteration. If you *have to* use `For`, you can initialize `sol` to `{}` in the first argument of `For` and use [`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) to append new solutions (below, I used `g''[t]` for your `H[t]`):

```
For[sol = {}; e = 0, e < 6, e++, 
    AppendTo[sol, 
      First@NDSolve[{g''[t] == -e*g[t], g[0] == g[2*Pi], g[Pi] == 1}, 
          g[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]]];
Plot[Evaluate[Flatten[g[t] /. sol]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> ("e = " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[0, 5])]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Table`:

```
sol2 = Table[First@NDSolve[{g''[t] == -e*g[t], g[0] == g[2*Pi], g[Pi] == 1}, 
          g[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}], {e, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[Flatten[g[t] /. sol2]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> ("e = " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[0, 5])]
```

> same picture

A much better approach is to create a parametric solution using [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) or [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) (as suggested by Sjoerd in the comments):

```
pndsv = ParametricNDSolveValue[{g''[t] == -a*g[t], g[0] == g[2*Pi], g[Pi] == 1}, 
    g, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {a}];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pndsv[a][t], {a, 0, 5, 1}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> All,  PlotLegends -> ("e = " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[0, 5])]
```

> same picture